# Error JS - salida por pantalla

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas a tod@s una vez más,

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo una estructura HTML que tengo que modificar de la siguiente manera:

-He de añadir antes del botón un h1, un línea de separación (hr) y un div con un p dentro.
-He de cambiar el texto del enlace y la dirección a la que hace referencia.

Pues bien, cuando aplico los cambios (pulsando el botón), únicamente se cambia la dirección del enlace.

Cualquier ayuda será bienvenida, así que gracias a tod@s por adelantado.

Un saludo

```js
function crearBody_modificarEnlace(){
    var hache1 = document.createElement("h1");
    var textoHache = document.createTextNode("Encabezado dinámico");
    hache1.appendChild(textoHache);
    
    var salto = document.createElement("hr");
    
    var division = document.createElement("div");
    var parrafo = document.createElement("p");
    var textoParrafo = document.createTextNode("Párrafo creado dinámicamente");
    division.appendChild(parrafo);
    parrafo.appendChild(textoParrafo);

    var enlace = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    enlace.setAttribute("href","http://www.wikipedia.org");
    var textoEnlace = document.createTextNode("Ir a Wikipedia");
    enlace.replaceChild("text", textoEnlace);

    var cuerpo = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var boton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
    cuerpo.insertBefore(division, boton);
    cuerpo.insertBefore(salto, division);
    cuerpo.insertBefore(hache1,salto);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Construyendo el DOM</title>

    <style>
        @import "estilo.css";
    </style>
    <script src="codigo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="crearBody_modificarEnlace();">Crear body y Cambiar enlace</button>
    <p><a href="http://www.google.es">Ir a Google</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`replaceChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) sustituye un nodo por otro dado un **parentNode**. En este caso estamos trabajando con un **elemento** llamado `enlace`.

Para **sustituir un texto por otro dentro de un elemento** mejor usar [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText).

El código en este caso quedaría así:

```
// var textoEnlace = document.createTextNode("Ir a Wikipedia");
// enlace.replaceChild("text", textoEnlace);
enlace.innerText = "Ir a Wikipedia";
```

También es posible usar [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) debido a que un **elemento** es un tipo de nodo:

```
enlace.textContent = "Ir a Wikipedia";
```

```js
function crearBody_modificarEnlace(){
    var hache1 = document.createElement("h1");
    var textoHache = document.createTextNode("Encabezado dinámico");
    hache1.appendChild(textoHache);
    
    var salto = document.createElement("hr");
    
    var division = document.createElement("div");
    var parrafo = document.createElement("p");
    var textoParrafo = document.createTextNode("Párrafo creado dinámicamente");
    division.appendChild(parrafo);
    parrafo.appendChild(textoParrafo);

    var enlace = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    enlace.setAttribute("href","http://www.wikipedia.org");
    enlace.textContent = "Ir a Wikipedia";

    var cuerpo = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var boton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
    cuerpo.insertBefore(division, boton);
    cuerpo.insertBefore(salto, division);
    cuerpo.insertBefore(hache1,salto);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="crearBody_modificarEnlace();">Crear body y Cambiar enlace</button>
    <p><a href="http://www.google.es">Ir a Google</a></p>
```

Comment: Buenas!

Pues esto lo soluciona exactamente. De hecho, esto estaba bloqueando la salida por pantalla de todo lo demás.

No sé exactamente a que te refieres con que me he complicado, pero seguramente, porque me da la impresión de que hay una manera más elegante, pero es que no se me ocurre. De hecho, lo peor que veo es en la inclusión de los nuevos nodos. Creo que tiene que haber una manera mejor de sacar una serie de elementos organizados de una manera determinada. Si no te importa y puedes ser más específico lo agradecería, para así poder solventarlo.

Muchas gracias por la solución :D

Comment: Bueno, me referia concretamente al `replaceChild()`, que sustituye un nodo por otro (y no un texto por otro como ha hecho el `innerText` en este caso).  Allí estaba tu error. El resto no me parece ni mal ni bien, tampoco me he parado mucho a pensarlo pues no era tu pregunta concreta :-)

Comment: Ah, vale! Me alegro de que, al menos en apariencia, no se perciba ningún error gordo. Como estoy aprendiendo, creo que me puedo dar por satisfecho con que el código sea funcional :S

De nuevo muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Es decir, no me cuestiono lo que estan haciendo los OP (Original Poster) en su código, entiendo que tienen sus razones para hacerlo de determinado modo en cada ocasión.  Quizás porque no saben más, quizas porque es un ejercicio que les obligan a usar nodos, quizas porque no quieren cambiarlo todo, etc... Es decir, me limito a solucionar problemas de errores que tengais, si puedo, a la vez que aprendo de vosotros pues dificilmente a mi se me plantean vuestras dudas al no tener los casos que vosotros teneis.

Comment: Te entiendo perfectamente y lo único que puedo decir es que agradezco que haya personas como tú dispuestas a ayudar a otros que estamos empezando en esto. Es para tenerlo muy en cuenta y ponerlo en valor.

Comment: Gracias a ti por tu comprensión. Acabo de editar la respuesta agregando un poco más de explicación complementaria.